# pgf-pie and babel incompatibility?

Tags: babel, incompatibility, pgf-pie

I'm having a rather strange problem with pgf-pie: it seems not to work very well when using the babel package...

See for yourself:

**Without babel**

[image: without babel]

**With babel**

[image: with babel]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,final]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[polar]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[square]{40/A, 30/B, 20/C, 10/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[cloud, text=inside, scale font]{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Has anyone seen this before? How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. `babel` makes some characters active, which can mess with parts of the TikZ machinery. That library deals with those issues.

Comment: This solved the problem indeed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mine as well, this comment should be an answer.