# Help with pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I'm new to use LaTeX. I'm trying to make a pie chart with `pgf-pie` package but when I compile, there are some number in front of the text like this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \pie[text=pin, rotate=90, sum=100]
             {14/Autres causes environnementales ,
              21/CMV , 41/Autres causes génétiques ,
              3/Syndrome de Pendred  , 21/GJB2}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \newline
      \caption{\'Epidémiologie des surdités congénitales, d'après\cite{Morton2006}}
      \label{epidemio}  
    \end{table}
```

When I try with the example, I've got the same problem. Could someone help me to remove that numbers? Thanks!

Comment: Please add a `MWE`. Here, your code compiles well when using `pgf-pie` package.

Comment: Seems to work fine with me: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/561b73ec7694a256397bc5da

Comment: As others have said, your code works fine on updated systems. Can you do the following: Take LaRiFaRi's code in the answer below, add `\listfiles` just before `\documentclass`, and compile. Then open the `.log` file and near the end you will find a list of all packages used and their version numbers. Copy this into your question. My first guess would be that you have an old version of pgf/TikZ, in which case updating would fix this.

Comment: I'll find the answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256612/pgf-pie-and-babel-incompatibility), it was a copatibility problem with babel. Thank for your answers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is due to code not included in the question. (No MWE and the crucial incompatibility is not hinted at in any way, so all attempts to reproduce by completing the code in the obvious ways failed utterly.) The OP solved the problem independently and this question is, therefore, about a problem whose cause nobody could possibly have ascertained in order to answer.

Comment: @cellaure This is precisely why all questions should include a minimal working example which can be compiled to reproduce the issue or a minimal non-working example which reproduces the error when compiled. In this case, nobody but you had access to the information relevant to the issue, so all efforts to help you were doomed from the start. See Denis's first comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a comment. Please try my following MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}% why table? figure would be more apropriate, I think
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pie[text=pin, rotate=90, after number=\,\%]
            {14/Autres causes environnementales,
            21/CMV, 41/Autres causes génétiques,
            3/Syndrome de Pendred, 21/GJB2}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Épidémiologie des surdités congénitales, d'après \cite{Morton2006}}\label{epidemio}  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If this does result in your output, we have to compare the used versions of packages. If it does work, please try to find the differences between your case and mine and explain them to us.